# EXCEL : two-bar, 2-axis histogram

Tags: excel, histogram

I hope to show an two-bar, 2-axis histogram but when i do that on EXCEL I get an stacked, 2-axis histogram

[image]

The result I currently want is like that :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick the Chart select CHANGE CHART TYPE change chart type to CLUSTERED:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did this, but when I use 2 axes it stacks the graph

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Can't find a solution :-(